# Quotients of Solvable Groups are Solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, solvable-groups

I just proved that subgroups of solvable groups are solvable. So given that $G$ is solvable there is $1=G_0 \unlhd G_1 \unlhd \cdots \unlhd  G_s=G$ where $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian and for $N$ a normal subgroup we know it is solvable so there is $1=N_0 \unlhd N_1 \unlhd \cdots \unlhd N_{r}=N$ where $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian.

I'm trying to construct the chain for the entire group $G/N$ using the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem but am stuck. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You have a run-on sentence starting with "So given that".  It would be clearer if it were at least two sentences.

Comment: Oops didn't see that. Idk how that happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "standard" proof:

Consider, for each $i$, the subgroups $G_iN/N$ of $G/N$. It is straight-forward to show that $G_iN$ is normal in $G_{i+1}N$ (and thus $G_iN/N$ is normal in $G_{i+1}N/N$).

Now $\dfrac{G_{i+1}N/N}{G_iN/N} \cong G_{i+1}N/G_iN$.

Taking any $x,y \in G_{i+1}$, and $n,n' \in N$, we see that:

$[xn(G_iN),yn'(G_iN)] = [xn,yn']G_iN$, and since $N \lhd G$, $[xn,yn'] \in [x,y]N$, so that:

$[xn,yn']G_iN = [xn,yn']NG_i = ([xn,yn']N)G_i = $

$([x,y]N)G_i = [x,y]NG_i = [x,y]G_iN = ([x,y]G_i)N$.

Since $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian, $[x,y]G_i = G_i$ so $[xn,yn']G_iN = G_iN$,so that

$G_{i+1}N/G_iN$ is abelian, as desired.

(here, $[x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ and we are using the fact that for a group $G$, $G$ is abelian iff $[x,y] = e$ for all $x,y \in G$).

It should be noted that some of the quotients $G_{i+1}N/G_iN$ may be trivial, resulting in a shorter subnormal series for $G/N$.

Comment: Can you explain why $([xn,yn']NG_i)=[x,y]NG_i$?

Comment: +1 - This is a great answer. Thought I might share a slightly different (but honestly equivalent to David's answer) way of showing/phrasing that $G_{i+1}N/G_iN$ is abelian ---  Note that for $N\trianglelefteq G, aN,bN$ commute iff $[a,b] \in N$. Thus, using the fact that $N$ is normal we have $[xn,yn'] = [x,y]n_0$. Since $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian and since $x,y \in G_{i+1}$ it follows that $[x,y] \in G_i$. Thus $[x,y]n_0 \in G_iN$ as desired.

Answer (score 5):

(Corrected) Note that since the chain starts at $1<N$, there exists a maximun $i$ such that $G_i<N$. Multiplying and quotienting out that part of the chain gives a chain of quotients $1\lhd NG_i/N\lhd \cdots \lhd G/N$ and $(NG_{i+1}/N)/(NG_i/N)\simeq NG_{i+1}/NG_i\hookrightarrow G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian. The argument is essentially the same as the following: suppose that $\eta:G\to H$ is onto and $G$ is solvable. Then $H$ is solvable.

There's another part to the story: if $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable, show that $G$ is solvable too.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with the first term in your chain. In particular, this requires that $(G_{i}/N)/1 \cong G_{i}/N$ be abelian. But how do we know this is abelian? It is true that $(G_{i+1}/N)/(G_{i}/n) \cong G_{i+1}/G_{i}$ for all of them in the chain except for the first one (unless the minimum $G_{i}$ containing $N$ happens to be $G_{i}=N$.

Comment: I've never seen the symbol used after $NG_{i+1}/NG_i$, the curved arrow.  Since this may be a concept or at least some notation which is usually encountered later than this particular exercise, it might deserve some explanation.

Comment: @Addem A 'hook' at the tail of an arrow usually means that function is injective.

Comment: @Pedro How did you get an injection $NG_{i+1}/NG_i\hookrightarrow G_{i+1}/G_i$?